# SQL Server: Getting "before two days" date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select, and I need to limit data only for two last days. So today is 24th Aug 2016 so I need to get data for 24th Aug 2016, 23th Aug 2016 and 22th Aug 2016. How can I do that? I suppose I should use DATEADD function, or something similar. It needs to be done dynamicaly.

I need to get something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE
DATE = '2016-08-22'
```

The date must be updated each day

Answer (score 5):

DateAdd, exactly

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN  dateadd(d,-2,cast(getDate() as date)) AND  cast(getDate() as date)
```

Comment: `dateadd(d,-2,cast(getDate() as date))` this part should be `cast as date`, too I think

Comment: It will be casted implicitly. Anyway the result will be the same provided [DATE] column is of `Date` type. The main reason of cast is  to round getdate(). See `select 1 where cast(getDate() as date) = dateadd(d,0,cast(getDate() as date))`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE
cast(DATE as date) >= cast(GETDATE()-2 as date)
```

or
     --For limiting future dates

```
  SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 
    WHERE
    cast(DATE as date)  in (cast(GETDATE()-2 as date),cast(GETDATE()-1 as date), cast(GETDATE() as date))
```

Use `GETDATE()` function

Comment: Why are you using CAST?

Comment: getdate() returns datetime. So when when comparison is done it will compare both date and time. we need to compare only date. if your date column is of type 'date' then cast is not needed for date column. i assumed it to be string

Comment: Akshey, if there's a future date in the table, your query will return it but it should not

Comment: @TedoG.added an alternate version of query to limit future dates

Comment: Good, but in the post he says that he wants 3 dates: today, today - 1 and today - 2, you still need a simple edit I think

Comment: @TedoG.Edited query to include today's date. Thanks for sharing your observation

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE cast(DATE as date) BETWEEN cast(DATEADD(D, -2, GETDATE()) as date) AND cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are future dates in this table you can perhaps use this

```
select * from table_name
where date <= getdate()
and date >= dateadd(day,-2,getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE
DATE >=cast(getdate()-2 as date)--so this will be rounded off to midnight and it is sargable
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make today's date in absolute by converting it in float then floor and then convert it into small date time. And then using dateadd subtract 2 days from today's absolute date.

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE_NAME 
WHERE 
DATE >= (SELECT DATEADD(dd,-2,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() as FLOAT)) as SMALLDATETIME)))
```